# New Blockchain.info wallet but where are my bitcoins? How to access them?

Tags: blockchain.info

I have/had a wallet with Blockchain.info containing 2 bitcoin addresses. One address contained 0.33 BTC.

Yesterday when I wanted to access my wallet, for whatever reason, I couldn't remember my password, so I thought, no issue, I just can re-enter my wallet using my 12 words, so I did. I tried to recover my wallet with these 12 words and I was given another wallet (another wallet ID I mean).

The problem here is that I cannot see my funds and my known bitcoin address! I can import the bitcoin address (as I can for any address but then it is 'read only').

Can someone explain me / help me how I can recover my funds? These funds have always been in my old wallet (former wallet-ID).

Comment: You can't offer money for answers.

Comment: When did you first create the wallet? Very old blockchain.info wallets have a multi word recover phrase (it may be 12 words, I don't quite remember) which actually correspond to some encoding of the password and not a BIP 39 seed that is used today.

Comment: Hi, the wallet was created at blockchain.info more than a year ago, maybe 1,5y. I have a 12 word recovery phrase which I used beleiving it would bring me a copy paste of the contents of my old wallet. Unfortunately it only recovered one address with almost no money on it. The other one is lost for now.

Answer (score 1):

This method will only work if you didn't imported any addresses to your account. (Reason? "Please note that imported addresses are not backed up by the wallet recovery phrase. We strongly recommend you sweep funds from imported addresses." [Source](https://blog.blockchain.com/2016/04/20/support-team-tips-why-your-wallet-recovery-phrase-is-so-important/))

First go to [Electrum](https://electrum.org/#download) and download the wallet from there.

Then install & open that wallet.

While opening, select "standard wallet"

Then select "I have a seed"

After that you will get a screen like this where you need to import your 12 word seed:

[image]

Then click on "options"

[image]

After that click on "BIP39 Seed"

[image]

Then the wallet will have your BTC with the same address.

Hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: I will definitely give it a try once my options run out at blockchain.info altough I am afraid it will only recover one of the two addresses as it did while recovering at blockchain.info. The other address, that is not recovered yet, is missing. I can import it, as I can import any given address, but I do not have control over it (status= 'read only'. The wallet needs to know that the address belongs to me and that I can have control... I hope I make myself clear...

Comment: What you said is clear mate, but if the address where you have balance was created from the seed itself, then that should have recovered using the same seed.

Answer (score -1):

Check in your sent and received transactions if you have the transactions in there.Check the chain if your wallet has any outgoing transactions. Else i think you can recover with your mail id as they ask it while creating the wallet

Comment: No, it's not possible through the email, since blockchain.info using client side encryptions for wallets. and you can register in blockchain using exist email more than once since they don't have database to store users email or info.

Comment: Hi all, I do see some transactions from the past from 1 of the 2 addresses I have. But the second address that was in my wallet has not been recovered so far. It is the one holding the funds. I assume I need to import it some way or another?